# How to compute gradient of complicated scalar function ( limit and iteration)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods, differential-operators, complex-dynamics

I have a function which gives scalar potential:

$$P(c) =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \ln|f^{n}_c(0)|$$

where:

- $c$ is complex variable
- $f$ is [the complex quadratic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_quadratic_polynomial)

$$f_c(z) = z^2 + c$$

- $f^n$ denotes [iteration ( function composition )](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function)

$$f^{n+1} ~ \stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=} ~ f \circ f^n$$

I would like to compute **gradient** of function P: $\nabla P $

I can approximate it using [numerical methods](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gradient_of_potential.svg):
[image]

**Question: How can I compute gradient of function P: $\nabla P $  using symbolic methods ?**

I have found only one [description by Linas Vepstas](https://linas.org/art-gallery/escape/ray.html)

> The gradient 2Df always points 'uphill':

$2Df = \frac{f z_n Dz_n }{ |z_n|^2 log |z_n|}$

Comment: https://hoyleanalytics.org/2017/05/20/faa-di-bruno-and-derivatives-of-an-iterated-function/